# Something happend to my desktop environment when I tried to change it

Tags: gnome, budgie

Im not quite sure what happend and how to fix it. It tried to switch my DE to Budgie and followed this guide:

http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/11/09/install-budgie-desktop-ubuntu-16-04-16-10/ (even though im on ubuntu 18.04).

I was not quite satisfied and tried to switch back by removing it (also in the guide) and now my `dash to dock` dock does not work properly, the default dock is also shown. And my terminal looks like this:

[image]

Notice the name and path in the top as well as the wierd symbol in the right corner.

What can have happend?

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I don't know if you're new to Linux, I am, and I was in a similar place as you about a month ago. It's generally just a bad idea to change back and forth on Desktop Environments. Things get all wonky and twisted out of shape. Honestly really the only way to deal with this thing is to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 from scratch. I also recommend that next time you want to try out a new DE, use a VM because that can keep everything pretty clean and won't break stuff as much.